# How to show a fragment in all Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, show

I have an activity (activity A) and a fragment A, part of activity A. I am opening another activity (activity B). How to show fragment A (if fragment A visible) in activity B?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Include fragment tag in ur second activity and pass the instance of FragmentA to it

Comment: @Ganesh: thanks very much!

Comment: No problem. Accept my answer if it solves your problem ... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Include `<fragment>` tag in ur **second activity**'s Layout
- Get the **instance** of **FragmentA** in Second Activity
- Set that instance to your `<fragment>` progarmatically .